# How to read a delimited text file and export the data into individual columns of an excel sheet in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, delimiter

The file that I am importing consists of tabs and commas, which will both need to be excluded from the the new excel sheet. I can't exactly figure this out and this is the code I have stared to use so far....Any help would be appreciated

```
Sub DelimitedTextFileToArray()
Dim Delimiter As String
Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileContent As String
Dim LineArray() As String
Dim DataArray() As String
Dim TempArray() As String
Dim rw As Long, col As Long

Delimiter = ","'I just used the comma as a test for the delimiter
FilePath = "C:\FILENAME.txt"
rw = 0

TextFile = FreeFile
Open FilePath For Input As TextFile

FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)


Close TextFile


LineArray() = Split(FileContent, vbCrLf)

For x = LBound(LineArray) To UBound(LineArray)
  If Len(Trim(LineArray(x))) <> 0 Then
      TempArray = Split(LineArray(x), Delimiter)

    'Determine how many columns are needed
      col = UBound(TempArray)

    'Re-Adjust Array boundaries//Ive had problems debugging @ this step and beyond
      ReDim Preserve DataArray(col, rw)

    'Load line of data into Array variable
      For y = LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray)
        DataArray(y, rw) = TempArray(y)
      Next y
  End If

    rw = rw + 1

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't tell without an example of your data and your desired output, but you could probably just use Power Query.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
TempArray = Split(LineArray(x), Delimiter)
```

with

```
TempArray = Split(Replace(LineArray(x), vbTab, Delimiter), Delimiter)
```

That will make every tab a comma prior to splitting

Comment: Semicolon? do you mean tab instead - like `vbTab`?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Will fix.